# Des expressions en français qui signifient "créer portfolio papier pour les dossiers" sur un ordinateur?

Tags: informatique, technologie

Quelles sont les deux ou trois expressions en français qui signifient "créer un répertoire" sur un ordinateur ?

Comment vous exprimez-vous 《 faire  un dossier 》ou 《 créer un dossier 》en français ?

De nombreux sites Web sont gérés sur des ordinateurs électroniques (ordinateurs portables et téléphones portables) aux États-Unis qui utilisent un système d'exploitation connu sous le nom de "**Linux**". La commande Linux `mkdir` est une abréviation de l'expression anglaise `make directory`.

Quelle expression française entendez-vous utilisée par les programmeurs informatiques pour signifier "créer un répertoire" ou l'une des suivantes ?

- Créer un dossier de manille vide [emoji de dossiers]
- Faites une nouvelle feuille de papier vierge pliée en deux [emoji de dossiers]
- Créer un portfolio papier. [emoji de dossiers]
- Produire ou fournir des contenants vides pour les dossiers. [emoji de dossiers]
- Établir un nouvel emplacement pour mettre les choses [emoji de dossiers]

Comment: D'où sortent ces expression ? Je n'ai entendu aucune de celles-ci. On dit juste "créér un dossier" ou plus rarement "créér un répertoire" (qui est un peu désuet "années 80 MS-DOS") .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

« Faire un dossier » peut, à la rigueur, être utilisé, mais ça n'est pas aussi spécifique que  « créer un dossier », qui est le terme courant. [Microsoft Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/cr%C3%A9er-un-dossier-cbbfb6f5-59dd-4e5d-95f6-a12577952e17)

« Dossier » semble être maintenant le terme précis pour différencier les  dossiers—qui étaient appelés « répertoire » ou « dossier »—des répertoires racine, qui sont  appelés « racine » aujourd'hui : [Microsoft Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/topic/un-dossier-est-cr%C3%A9%C3%A9-sous-la-racine-du-lecteur-syst%C3%A8me-manque-des-entr%C3%A9es-dans-son-descripteur-de-s%C3%A9curit%C3%A9-ce-qui-risque-de-provoquer-des-d%C3%A9faillances-de-l-application-sur-la-version-anglaise-de-l-%C3%A9dition-int%C3%A9grale-de-windows-7-release-candidate-32-bits-cf8aaca9-e52b-b1c7-056a-a3dee8d601cf), [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9pertoire_racine).

On doit quand même pouvoir utiliser le terme « répertoire racine » qui reste correct.

- Créer un dossier de manille vide (*non, ne correspond pas à ce qui est créé*)
- Faites une nouvelle feuille de papier vierge pliée en deux (*non, pas idiomatique*)
- Créer un portfolio papier. (*non, ne correspond pas à ce qui est créé*)
- Produire ou fournir des contenants vides pour les dossiers. (*non, pas idiomatique*)
- Établir/créer un nouvel emplacement  (*choix possible*)

Comment: Si j'entendais "Faire un dossier", je trouverais l'expression bizarre. En pratique, on utilise aussi les termes anglais directement ...

Answer (score 2):

La réponse concise est « créer un dossier ».